# how to add beat and bass effect in video using ffmpeg command?

Tags: ios, swift, ffmpeg

i want beat effect on video and i am using ffmpeg command for beat effect i was used this below command for beat effect black and white and original color after 2 sec looping but not this work this command only create black and white video ffmpeg -i addition.mp4 -vf hue=s=0 output.mp4

So please, suggest any solution.

I want make video like [youtube.com/watch?v=7fG7TVKGcqI](http://youtube.com/watch?v=7fG7TVKGcqI) plaese suggest me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg -i addition.mp4 -vf hue=s=0 output.mp4` will, as you said, just create a black video. `vf` is video filters and `hue=s=0` is setting the hue and saturation to 0.

As far as I know, this kind of effect is way too advanced for a command line application unless you have a lot of knowledge on it already. I'd recommend using a graphical video editor. I use shotcut and I like it, but I'm not sure if you can do this in it.